# Find text in subquery with count in outer query

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm working with a film database (imdb) and I'm having difficulties using subquery. Learning in school and still at a fairly basic level.

I am supposed to find the number of parts in every parttype (actor, director, etc...) per film amongst cinema films which contains 'Lord of the Rings' as part of the title. The table Filmitem contains a column with filmtype whereas 'C' defines movies.

This is what I've got so far, but i only get (0 rows):

```
SELECT f.title, fp.parttype, count(*) as antall_deltagere
FROM filmparticipation fp
INNER JOIN film f
  ON fp.filmid = f.filmid
LEFT JOIN filmitem fi
  ON fi.filmid = fp.filmid
WHERE filmtype = 'C' AND title IN (
 SELECT title
  FROM film
  WHERE title = 'Lord of the Rings'
)
GROUP BY f.title, fp.parttype;
```

Answer (score 0):

"as part of the title" does not mean "equal to" maybe this will help?

```
SELECT
      f.title
    , fp.parttype
    , COUNT(*) AS antall_deltagere
FROM filmparticipation fp
INNER JOIN film f ON fp.filmid = f.filmid
LEFT JOIN filmitem fi ON fi.filmid = fp.filmid
WHERE filmtype = 'C'
AND title IN (
      SELECT
            title
      FROM film
      WHERE title LIKE '%Lord of the Rings%' -- using like
)
GROUP BY
      f.title
    , fp.parttype;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!
I actually managed to figure it out after a while, but I found a way to shorten the cuery a little:

[...]
WHERE f.title LIKE '%Lord of the Rings%'
AND (fi.filmtype LIKE '%C'%')
GROUP BY [...]